# template code declared outside of class doesn't compile

Tags: c++, templates

I want to declare the constructor outside of the class but there is something wrong with the template code.

```
template <size_t size = 1>
class my_class
{
public:
    template <class int_t>
    constexpr my_class(int_t);
};

template<class int_t, size_t size>
constexpr my_class<size>::my_class(int_t num)
{

}
```

but this works:

```
template <size_t size = 1>
class my_class
{
public:
    template <class int_t>
    constexpr my_class(int_t) {};
};
```

or:

```
template <size_t size = 1>
class my_class
{
public:
    constexpr my_class();
};

template<size_t size>
constexpr my_class<size>::my_class()
{

}
```

I have no idea why this doesn't work.
I asked ChatGPT but it told me that there is no error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `my_class` constructor function is a template *inside* a template. You can't combine templates inside templates as a single template, especially not in the wrong order.

You need two `template` declarations:

```
template<size_t size>
template<typename int_t>
constexpr my_class<size>::my_class(int_t num)
{

}
```

Please note that the order of the templates matters.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be

```
template <size_t size>
template <class int_t>
constexpr my_class<size>::my_class(int_t num)
{ /*... */ }
```